# Crashlytics Failed to load settings error

Tags: ios, crashlytics

I have Crashlytics integrated in my app but recently it stopped sending crash reports. Unfortunately, it's not because there aren't any.

I've turned on the debug mode of Crashlytics and this is what I see in the log:

```
[Crashlytics] Loading settings
[Crashlytics] Settings url string: 'https://settings.crashlytics.com/spi/v1/platforms/ios/apps/FOOBAR'
[Crashlytics] Settings response: {status: 502, error: (null)}
[Crashlytics] Failed to load settings
[Crashlytics] Settings load scheduled (600)
```

Could this be the reason? Is there anything I can do about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out it was just a minor hick-up while they were updating their servers. I have to express my thanks to Mike from Crashlytics who promptly reached out and explained the situation. Great customer service!

Answer (score 0):

Do you have your bundle identifier set to FOOBAR instead of a com.company.something setting?

Comment: I used FOOBAR just as a placeholder, otherwise it's set to the bundle identifier.

Comment: I would contact Crashlytics support as they have nearly instant response times.